# Handling multiple Accelerometer sensor

Tags: android, android-sensors

I have a hardware device with custom android os installed. I have integrated 2 accelerometer sensor embedded in it and properly integrated so that i was able to get data from 1 accelerometer using Android SensorManager use the belove code
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html

My question is what should i do to get data from both the accelerometer sensors.

Any suggestions/directions are much appreciated.